# Empty S3 remote log files in Airflow 2.3.2

Tags: airflow

I configured remote S3 logging with the following variables:

```
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING
    value: 'True'
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
    value: 's3://my-airflow/airflow/logs'
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
    value: 'my_s3'
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL
    value: 'ERROR'
  - name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS
    value: 'False'
```

So far the log files are created with the DAG and task path with the name `attempt=1.log` or similar but always with 0 bytes size (empty). When I try to see the logs from Airflow I get this message (I'm using the `KubernetesExecutor`):

```
*** Falling back to local log
*** Trying to get logs (last 100 lines) from worker pod  ***

*** Unable to fetch logs from worker pod  ***
(400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'f3e0dd67-c8f4-42fc-945f-95dc42e8c2b5', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 01 Aug 2022 13:07:07 GMT', 'Content-Length': '136'})
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"name must be provided","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}\n'
```

Why are my logs files empty?

Comment: I have exact same issue only with 2.3.4. Where you able to find the solution by any chance?

Comment: Hi @OlegYamin, sadly I did not... I'm thinking about changing the the logging backend to ElasticSearch. I'll update this question if anything comes up!